# Unable to render anything using angular js on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angular-ui-router

I am following this tutorial https://thinkster.io/angular-rails to setup angular js on RoR. I am stuck here as it is not rendering home.html partial present with in assets/javascripts/home/_home.html. browser shows blank screen even though i have added html and angular in _home.html. please help me out

**app.js**

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router','templates'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
        return posts.getAll();
    }]
}
    })
    .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree .
```

**_home.html**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
        ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
      {{post.upvotes}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
          {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
          {{post.title}}
        </span>
      </span>
      <span>
        <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
      </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPost()"
      style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Add a new post</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Title"
        ng-model="title"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Link"
        ng-model="link"></input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
  </script>
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

**routes**

root to: 'application#angular'

**application_controller.rb**

```
def angular
 render 'layouts/application'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I read your post, and the original tutorial correctly, it looks like you are pulling out some of the code that the tutorial had originally put in the application file, and trying to put it into a partial entitled _home.html

The major problem is that you don't tell application to render the partial anywhere. You would need to add

```
<%= render "home" %>
```

where you want that partial to appear on the page. This will render the partial _home.html.erb (your file above is labeled "_home.html," this is the minor problem).

You can get a lot of background on "render" and partials here: [PARTIALS](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) and [PARTIALS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)